# how to list “shared with me” items via new OneDrive api?

Tags: onedrive

I need to connect to OneDrive and fetch the list of shared files on the same for a given account.
Looking forward for help.

Comment: I have used wl.contacts_skydrive scope but getting following error { "error": { "code": "request_token_unauthorized", "message": "The access token doesn't have the correct permission for the resource. The access token must include one of the following scopes: 'wl.contacts_skydrive', 'wl.contacts_photos'." } }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this list of objects using the REST API, details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659731.aspx#get_a_list_of_onedrive_objects_that_are_shared_with_the_signed-in_user.

> To discover all OneDrive objects that are shared with the signed-in user, use the wl.contacts_skydrive scope to make a GET request to /USER_ID/skydrive/shared, where USER_ID is either me or the user ID of the sharing user. The sharing user must be one of the signed-in user's contacts, who has shared their OneDrive objects with the user. Here's an example:

`GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/shared?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: I have used wl.contacts_skydrive scope but getting following error 

{
    "error": {
        "code": "request_token_unauthorized",
        "message": "The access token doesn't have the correct permission for the resource. The access token must include one of the following scopes: 'wl.contacts_skydrive', 'wl.contacts_photos'."
    }
}

Comment: Are you correctly getting the access token? Docs on the REST call to get an access token here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659750.aspx

Comment: thanks.. looks like I am missing something from my end. thanks for sharing links.

Comment: I figured out the issue from my end, I wasn't sending the correct scope - "wl.contacts_skydrive". 
Thanks, it's pretty helpful.